# Mute down the protected message for advance user

Tags: feature-request, protected-questions

The protected message on question take quite a lot of screen space and you get after a while of using the site.

> protected by {user}♦ {date}
>   This question is protected to prevent
>   "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers
>   by new users. To answer it, you must
>   have more than 10 reputation.

I suggest that for users with rep over X (you decide) the message would be a simple line with no highlight only with the text:

protected by {user} ♦ {date}

EDIT:

I see the down votes, but I still insist, The data displayed in the protection message is ** redundant** after some time and it pretty easy to figure out that you don't need to displayed it for this user.

It not far fetched to no want to see something over and over again, it is very like the "don't show me again" metaphor that many places have (in desktop or in the web). They use because the message becomes redundant after a while (sometimes after first use).

As for the "How often do you encounter protected question?" argument: Lets say the you have something that you run once a week, and it has a welcome screen, how annoying is it **not to be able** to skip this screen? Less annoying then if you needed to run that **every day** but still annoying.

Comment: There are lots of other places in the interface when status is accompanied by descriptive text, like closed questions. Should *all* of these be hidden for advanced users, or just protection?

Comment: @cody good point, yes I think that all those messages should be muted down for advance uers

Comment: @Shay Erlichmen: If this is not implemented, you can always try to hide the messages yourself via a user stylesheet in your browser. Something like `.question-status p { display: none }` would work.

Answer (score 12):

Why is this an issue? How many protected questions do you see every day?

Unless you are seeing dozens of protected questions a day, I don't know why this 2 lines of text would be so bothersome.

Comment: For example [Hidden features of Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python) which I visit a couple times a week. Also its not only two lines of redundant text, its 80px (height) of my screen.

Comment: @Shay, ah, the problem is that that question shouldn't exists at all ;)

Comment: @Shay Consider using [stackprinter](http://stackprinter.appspot.com/) to produce an HTML file you can use locally on your computer to read the question and answers.  It won't have the alert message, you'll be able to read it without paging through 6 pages of answers, and you don't even have to wait for it to load - reading it from your local hard drive will be very fast.

Comment: It's not about how many these questions exist, it's about questions that are [worth getting back to](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another). For me it just builds my own resistense to these messages.

Comment: The issue is that abusing certain form (the greyish box) to display redundant messages over and over again results in users building up resistance to these messages, taking down *useful* ones with them.  It's similar as to how most users *ignore* Yes/No dialogs from OS.